# SAP Web Intelligence

Tags: object, business-objects

I am new in SAP Web intelligence and creating new Report.

I need to Compute difference between consecutive Columns.

Suppose I have the following columns in report:

```
Column 1      Column 2       Column 3       Column 4
```

I need formula which I can use in variable to compute difference of values  between consecutive columns like `Column 1 and Column 2`, `Column 2 and Column 3`, `Column 3 and Column 4` and so on.

Please assist me.

Thanks & Regards

Gourav Joshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are different Type of Date Types you have in the Columns

There are several functions according to DataType U have

If it is Number data type : int : col1-col2 , col2-col3, col3-col4  use Minus :

If it date data Type There are Several Functions:

```
MonthsBetween(col1;col2)
DaysBetween(col1;col2)
```